# Exclude Spring Cloud Config Server from Spring boot unit test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

Given I have the following 3 Beans:

```
@Component
public class ServiceConfig {
    // This value is only available from the Spring Cloud Config Server
    @Value("${example.property}")
    private String exampleProperty;

    public String getExampleProperty() {
        return exampleProperty;
    }
}

@Component
public class S1 {
    int i = 1;
}

@Component
public class S2 {

    @Autowired
    S1 s1;

}
```

I want to be able to run the following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class S2Test {

    @Autowired
    S2 s;

    @Test
    public void t2() {
        System.out.println(s.s1.i);
    }

}
```

The issue I have is that since I want to test the `S2` class in isolation and since it uses `@Autowired` I must have a Spring context in my test, however when the Spring context is started it tries to create all 3 beans which includes the bean with `@Value`. Since this value is only available from Spring Cloud Config Server the context will fail to be created giving the error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'example.property' in string value "${example.property}"`.

> My Question is: How are properties read from Spring Cloud Config
>   Server handled in the application when unit tests are run, observe in
>   my test i dont even care about the config so I dont want to explicitly
>   have to set a value in my test just for the context to be started?

Comment: What are you using as your build tool? Gradle or Maven? Something else?

Comment: I am using Maven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some options.

1. You can create test profile. Then, you will need to create `application-test.yml` or `application-test.properties` file. There, you can set the same value for `example.property`. There, if you want to start some tests with `test` profile, you can add to your test class `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation. For these tests, `test` would be started.
2. You can set default value for `example.property` by typing `@Value("${example.property:SomeDefaultValue}")`. `SomeDefaultValue` will be inserted if property not found.

I'd suggest first approach. You can set proper profile with annotation and there you will make sure which profile config server will send to you.

Comment: This might work, but I personally dislike using profiles and default values for properties. I prefer that the application fail to start if a property is not present.

Comment: Ok, but your app need that value so you need to provide it in some way. Proper profile for tests is known practice I think (different datasources for example for tests) and this is why I would do by first approach. Actually, I do it on daily basis.

Comment: I'm just stating a preference, not criticizing:) I have just come across too many instances where errors were hidden because the wrong profile was enabled or because an expected property was not provided. I dislike profiles especially because they can have such a huge impact on the application configuration, while I prefer a fine grained approach. If I need a property for test, I like to include the property in the "src/test/resources/application.properties" file. If I need a special configuration for my test, then I create a test only configuration class.

Comment: Yeah, of course, no problem, I can understand your approach ;) Probably there are some cases where this approach is great :) I don't have that much experience in microservices (one app in spring cloud) and, personally, I really like all config in ymls in one place for all modules :)

Comment: Option 2 is a bad idea in case the property value is different in each runtime environment (dev, prod, test, ...). For example, if such property is the database connection string and the application in production fails to load the value from spring-cloud-config, it might end up using the test DB connection string specified as default value.

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest simply adding "spring.cloud.config.enabled" to false in "src/test/resources/application.properties" and adding a test value for "example.property"..

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
example.property=testvalue
```

This is simple and does not impact your code base.
IF needed, you could also us a MOCK web environment, and a custom test application configuration that does not include those beans.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestOnlyApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
```

Comment: It works fine without spring.cloud.config.enabled=false so i removed that one

Comment: Cool:) I only disable it in unit tests because I don't want them connecting to anything, but really it doesn't matter if it works:)

Comment: @Pytry It works without `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` because when Spring sees your "src/test/resources/application.properties" it stops load the "src/main/resources/application.properties". And `spring.cloud.config.enabled` is false by default. So config server is not used anymore. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @ieXcept I'll try it out, but the assumption I was making was that "spring.cloud.config.enabled" was being set to true through the use of properties or with an annotation, so setting it to false while testing would overwrite that setting since the test "application.properties|yml" takes precedence over the main file. It is good to note that if you specify a value in main, but do NOT set on in test, then the one in main should still be used; you only need to set the values of properties you want to be different.

Comment: @ieXcept Also, I think it is generally better to use my second option number (create a custom test context), as that gives you better control over your unit tests.